# Get last accessed timestamp value of a user in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, users

Im trying to display the last accessed field when a user logs in. 
For this I tried using User::getLastLoginTime() .
But this returns a fatal error saying

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Drupal\customize_block\Plugin\Block\ContractDetails::get() in /var/www/html/core/modules/user/src/Entity/User.php on line 265**

Here is my block ,in my custom module:

```
/**
 * Provides a 'Customized contract' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "customer_info",
 *   label = @Translation("Customer and contract info"),
 *   module = "user",
 *   context = {
 *     "current_user" = @ContextDefinition("entity:user", label = @Translation("Current User"))
 *   }
 * )
namespace Drupal\customize_block\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

class ContractInfo extends BlockBase {
 public function build() {
 $output='';
 global $base_url;
 $current_user = $this->getContext('current_user');
 $output.='<div>' . $current_user -> contextData . '</div>';

     return array(
      '#markup' => $output,
      '#cache' => array(
     'contexts' => array('url'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I calling this method correct way?

Answer (score 1):

`getLastLoginTime` is not a static method so you would not be able to call it statically like that. You need to get the current user object from a couple of different ways:

#### 1. Use the [Drupal::currentUser](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AcurrentUser/8).

This is easy, but not recommended to tightly-couple your block.

#### 2. Inject the `current_user` service into your Block by implementing [ContainerFactoryPluginInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Plugin!ContainerFactoryPluginInterface.php/interface/ContainerFactoryPluginInterface/8).

The disadvantage is that this also has a dependency on the container, but can be mocked.

#### 3. Use the Context system because blocks extend [ContextAwarePluginBase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8/search/ContextAwarePluginBase).

This is the recommended option in my opinion because there is already a current user context (as well as node contexts) for blocks.

```
 * @Block(
 *   ...
 *   context = {
 *     "current_user" = @ContextDefinition("type" = "entity:user", "label" => @Translation("Current User")
 *   }
 * )
```

Then `$current_user = $this->getContext('current_user')` will get the current user.

Unfortunately there is not a handbook page about using contexts so documentation is relegated to guessing things based on the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/1938688), which itself was no longer accurate at the time of writing this answer.

Interestingly some IDEs (*cough* PhpStorm 10 *cough*) choke on the above annotation syntax because.

#### Finally...

You should look at the documentation for render arrays and the changes to make markup safe.

Comment: I think this needs work if anyone wants to clarify and improve using ContextAware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry,  Im not aware of creating context for blocks. Should I attach this context when Im returning the block?

Comment: You should add the context hash above to your block annotation.

Comment: Ive added the context hash above the block. Im getting another fatal error this time : PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isRequired() on a non-object in /var/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Plugin/Context/ContextHandler.php on line 105 . Please look the updated code above. Is there anything that Im missing ?

Comment: I tried giving '@Plugin' instead of '@Block' , this time the page gets loaded but the block isnt showing up. It says " This block is broken or missing. You may be missing content or you might need to enable the original module." in the html.

Comment: You need to use `@Block` for block plugins. The issue is that the change record is no longer accurate :|

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @mradcliffe ,couple of things, for the starter, `"current_user" = @ContextDefinition("entity:user", label = @Translation("Current User"))` renders my block without any errors and I can access the current_user by `$current_user = $this->getContext('current_user');` (updated the snippet above) . But the properties are **protected** here and hence, Im not able to display it. Is there any way to display the protected properties other than _ReflectionClass_ like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334355/how-to-get-protected-property-of-object-in-php)

Comment: You should be able to use getters on the AccountInterface

Comment: Does that mean I have to call **getLastAccessedTime()**  ? Could you provide an example code just to make it easier. Sorry, Im quite new to OOPS.